Angular 17: Why is this code not rendering properly?
Output
As you can see in the above image the table is not been rendered properly, Can you help me render this properly.
Below is the relevant code:
'app.component.ts'
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
import { Product } from './product';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ProductComponent, CartComponent, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly products: Product[] = [
    new Product('Flamethrower', 100),
    new Product('Pillow', 200),
    new Product('Book', 300),
  ];
  cartItems: Product[] = [];

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartItems.push(product);
  }
}

'app.component.html'
<h2>Products</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
      <app-product
        [product]="product"
        (addToCartEvent)="addToCart($event)"
      ></app-product>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
...

'app.component.css'
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

'product.component.ts'
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product.component.css'
})
export class ProductComponent {
  @Input() product!: Product;
  @Output() addToCartEvent = new EventEmitter<Product>();

  addToCart() {
    this.addToCartEvent.emit(this.product);
  }
}

'product.component.html'
<td>{{ product.name }}</td>
<td>{{ product.price }}$</td>
<td><button (click)="addToCart()">Add To Cart</button></td>

Also with SSR, It breaks even more, specifically the Add to Cart Button in Product Component.
And Also I want to use a Separate Component for Product because I am trying to learn Angular, currently seeing communication between different component using this example.
I was Hoping for a regular table with each row displaying a product properties.
I have tried moving the <tr> tag from app component to product component but it makes the thing my displaying all rows on a single line.
Now I could provide a separate table for each row aka add the <table> tag in product component but I believe it will miss align each row due to different sizes of name and potentially prices.

Table expects all the components to be properly in order so
table -> thead -> tr -> th
and
table -> thead -> tr -> td
Since in the code, we are having a intermediate tag for app-product, this is messing up the table, we can solve it using component selectors!
For this particular scenario. Angular support different types of component selectors, so we can set the component to use the class selector, so the code will be
By doing this code change, there will be no extra tag created inbetween td and trs!
product.component.ts
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: '.app-product', // <- class selector, the component will attach for all elements with the class .app-product
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product.component.css'
})
export class ProductComponent {
  @Input() product!: Product;
  @Output() addToCartEvent = new EventEmitter<Product>();

  addToCart() {
    this.addToCartEvent.emit(this.product);
  }
}

app.component.html
<h2>Products</h2>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products" 
        class="app-product"
        [product]="product"
        (addToCartEvent)="addToCart($event)">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
...


Thanks, Helped me out, I understood easily
